# Openshift wildfly add application user

Tags: openshift, wildfly

I have a web app that is deployed on wildfly server that run in openShift cloud.

I have only one admin username. I want to add application users to that server.
I can run jboss-cli by using `rhc port-forward -a myAppName` but I couldn't find a way to add the user or run add-user.bat remotely or find out somehow a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates:**

I found the solution, with puTTy. [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/remote-connection.html)

and I add new user to ApplicationRealm with ease:

1. Connect to my app with puTTy
   2.Access wildfly bin directory
   3.Make this command ./add-user.sh

[image]